# useMutation problem with variables - argument is required, but it was not provided

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

I have a mutation laid out like this:

```
const UPDATE_UNIT_HOTLIST = gql`
  mutation unitUpdateById($unit_id: String!, $hot_list: Boolean!, $user_id: String!) {
    unitUpdateById(_id: $unit_id, user_id: $user_id, hot_list: $hot_list) {
      _id
      hot_list
    }
  }
`


 const [unitUpdateById] = useMutation(UPDATE_UNIT_HOTLIST)

  const formattedData = {
    unit_id: unit.id,
    hot_list: !isHotlist,
    user_id: sessionStorage.USER_ID,
  }

unitUpdateById({
      variables: formattedData,
    })
```

this keeps complaining about the below error:

> message: "Field "unitUpdateById" argument "_id" of type
> "String!" is required, but it was not provided."

What is wrong in this as all the data is being passed correctly :|

Comment: Is `unit.id` defined?